# In R, how to make a certain package namespace the chosen namespace in case of naming conflict?

Tags: r, r-package

In R, the order of when the packages are loaded matters.

Is there a way to make it such that the a certain package namespace is always the winner in a naming conflict regardless of order?

Comment: See the [`conflicted`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conflicted/index.html) package.

Comment: Specifically check out [conflict_prefer](https://conflicted.r-lib.org/reference/conflict_prefer.html)